# Solving Recurrence Relation Word Problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Consider the following:

> A bus driver pays all tolls, using only nickels and dimes, by throwing one coin at a time into the mechanical toll collector. Find a recurrence relation for the number of different ways the bus driver can pay a toll of n cents (where the order in which the coins are used matters).

The solution is $a_n = a_{n-5} + a_{n-10}$ With the base cases being $a_0 = 1$ and $a_5 = 1$. Could someone help clarify why this is the solution? I understand the second base case. $a_5 = 1$ because there is 1 way to pay a 5 cent toll. But I don't understand the first base case or the relation itself. What process can I follow to solve this word problem as well as others?

Comment: As to the recursion:  the last coin is either a nickel or a dime.  If a nickel, then the fellow must have gotten to $a_{n-5}$ first.  If a dime, then he must have reached $a_{n-10}$ and used a dime.

Comment: If you don't like $a_0=5$ (which just means "there is only one way to put no coins in a row") then use $a_{10}=2$ instead.

Comment: @lulu I understand the other base case now, thanks. But I'm still a little confused on the recurrence relation, why look at the last coin the first place?

Comment: Well...recursions generally try to build from smaller values to greater, this is just a way to do that.